# Supported Automation Framework for an Outsystems developed application

Tags: test-automation-framework, cucumber

In my company development team has started using tool called "[Outsystems](https://www.outsystems.com/) " which has less code and less managing issue while developing .

So I wanted to know from QA side if anyone's company is using Outsystems tool for development and they have started with any good Automation framework.

Does robot framework does this job well if anyone knows about this ?

It would be helpful if you could mention about the tool which supports well with Outsystems and reduce manual efforts too.

Comment: What did you try? Did you even read the Outsystems testing guidelines in their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has some suggestions:

> OutSystems generates 100% standard mobile and web apps, with a
> standard .NET web stack on the server side. As such, most testing
> tools on the market can be used for UI testing and load testing. For
> this reason, we won't recommend any specific tool here, but we'll
> focus on the aspects you should keep in mind to pick the best tool for
> your context.
>
> https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/Best_Practices/OutSystems_Testing_Guidelines/Automated_Testing_Tools

Seems the application can be automated with any modern web/app automation tool, but they suggest you use [BDDFramework](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-overview/1201/bddframework) which matches your cucumber tag.

Other reads:

- https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/Best_Practices/OutSystems_Testing_Guidelines